# QT Quick UI Forms: how expose custom signal from QML component and handle in javascript

Tags: qml, qtquick2

The QT Quick UI Forms example describes how to separate the declarative UI from the imperative javascript.

However, it does not describe how to make a custom signal that is exposed (declared?) at the declaritive level and handled in the javascript file.

The form is to be loaded in a shell application that needs to call fire custom signals we are calling: init and shutdown.

It seems I should be able to do this::

```
// MyComponent.ui.qml
Item {
   signal init()
}

// MyComponent.qml  javascript file
MyComponent {
  onInit : {
     // do some initialization
  }
}

// Usage in shell
MyComponent {
   id: mycomp
}

// somewhere
button.clicked: mycomp.init()
```

Comment: `Button { onClicked: mycomp.init(); }`, no?

Comment: The problem is that this init signal is not exposed and I get indication that init function does not exist. Also, isn't that declarative code that will cause QT designer to choke?

Answer (score 0):

The order of the references was incorrect.

Needs to be: 
Loader => MyComponent.qml (javascript) => MyComponentForm.ui.qml

But was:
Loader => MyComponentForm.ui.qml

// MyComponent.qml (javascript) was not referenced

Our loader was configured to load the declarative qml directly. Fixed by loading the javascript qml file. (which in turn referred to the MyComponentForm)

This way, our javascript init function was exposed. The module with imperative javascript extends the declarative qml with javascript functions.

```
// MyComponentForm.ui.qml
Item {
   // property aliases as required by imperative code
   // declarative ui stuff
}

// MyComponent.qml  javascript file
MyComponentForm {
  onInit : {
     // do some initialization
  }
}

Loader {
   anchors.fill: parent
   id: pageLoader
}

Button {
   onClicked {  
      source = "qrc://MyComponent.qml";
      pageLoader.item.init();
   }
}
```